# Angular 2+ Recursive Nesting Issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, nested, angular6

I'm experiencing a strange issue with recursively nested components. The nesting is based on an array where every next item will be one more level in nesting (the array within the chunk object is called entities):

```
<app-chunk [chunk]="chunk" [increment]="(increment + 1)"></app-chunk>
```

-

```
@Input() chunk;

ngOnInit() {
    // Check if it's the final nesting
    if (!this.chunk.entities || this.chunk.entities.length <= this.increment) {
      this.isThrough = true;
    } else {
      this.isThrough = false;
    }
  }
```

The nesting works fine so far, but, when I change the array, the changes are not reflected throughout the nested components.

e.g. Deleting from the array, should cause one level of the nested components to disappear, which is not happening. Basically, I would require a full re-render of the recursive component tree, right?

But, can this be done anyhow?
(already tried NgZone.run, ApplicationRef.tick) => no success yet

Comment: is chunk an array? how are you deleting items from array?

Comment: no, entities inside chunk is an array. I'm deleting with splice. The chunk object is handed over every recursive call, with increment giving the index of the entities array inside the chunk object.

Comment: The idea behind it is to have a word (chunk), that has tags (entities) --> Instead of showing a row of entities behind the word, I want to nest the word itself into the different tags. So every tag is a wrapper to a following tag and finally the wrapper for the text itself.

Comment: Any chance you can create a reproduction of this on StackBlitz or something for us to take a look at?

Comment: It might be because of the reason that splice does not create a new instance of the array object. It only removes the specified data. Since there is no change in the actual object instance, no change detection will run. You can try using `Object.assign([],array)` to create a new instance of object which will trigeer the change detection.

Comment: I will try that, thank you!

Comment: That didn't work. Unfortunately!

Comment: Object.assing only does shallow copies not deep copies. Instead use const newArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));